# SSHJ: exec hangs or loses data

Tags: sshj

I have used Trilead and Jsch to use as a SSH client for Hg, and now I'm trying it with SSHJ because it seems to provide more modern key support. The sketched code reads as

```
SSHClient client = createClientAndAuthenticate();
Session session = client.startSession();
Command cmd = session.exec(command); // command usually is "hg -R /path/to/hg/repository serve --stdio"

startThreadToCopyInputStream(cmd.getOutputStream());

startThreadToCopyOutputStream(cmd.getInputStream());
startThreadToCopyOutputStream(cmd.getErrorStream());

cmd.join(); // here it hangs endlessly
```

The `startThreadToCopyInputStream` method copies all bytes from the local Hg process to `cmd.getOutputStream()` and then finishes the input stream. But in contrast to Trilead and JSch the `cmd.getInputStream()` and `cmd.getErrorStream()` remain open endlessly.

I've now changed the code to something like:

```
SSHClient client = createClientAndAuthenticate();
Session session = client.startSession();
Command cmd = session.exec(command); // command usually is "hg -R /path/to/hg/repository serve --stdio"

startThreadToCopyInputStream(cmd.getOutputStream());

startThreadToCopyOutputStream(cmd.getInputStream());
startThreadToCopyOutputStream(cmd.getErrorStream());

waitUntilInputStreamIsClosed();
cmd.close();
```

This works fine in 90% of the cases, but sometimes Hg complains that the server closed the connection to early. How should I know when to be able to call `cmd.close()` because the server process has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in SSHJ (see [ticket 143](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/issues/143)). The work-around is to not use `cmd.getOutputStream()` directly, but instead:

```
OutputStream cmdOutputStream = new FilterOutputStream(cmd.getOutputStream()) {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            super.close();
        }
        finally {
            client.getTransport().write(new SSHPacket(Message.CHANNEL_EOF).putUInt32(session.getRecipient()));
        }
    }
};
```

before passing to `startThreadToCopyInputStream(cmdOutputStream);`.